# Does anybody know a command line tool for formatting MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql

I regularly have to debug large MySQL queries from a logfile and am looking for a tool to format and indent them - preferably windows command line, but will consider anything.

Answer (score 2):

[SQLinForm](http://www.sqlinform.com/) is a tool I came across which may serve your needs.  There is a free online version or a desktop version for 30 EUR.

Here is the summary blurb from their website:

> SQLinForm is an automatic SQL code
>   formatter for all major databases (
>   ORACLE, SQL Server, DB2 / UDB, Sybase,
>   Informix, PostgreSQL, Teradata, MySQL
>   etc) with many formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

You could use vi/vim to indent SQL queries. That's how I've been formatting them. However the drawback is that the query needs to be separated into multiple lines for the indentation to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) for formatting your queries. It has extensive and dynamic Query Formatter in which you can change background, foreground colors, font and other settings. [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) is also loaded with very powerful auto-complete feature.

[image: Query Formatter Screen Shot]